# Stripped header in request from client to server

Tags: apache, proxy, .net-core, angular7, kestrel

Recently I have transferred my simple application which consists of angular 7 client and asp .net core web api (.net core v2.2) to production environment and I encountered a strange problem. When I tried to make an action which should do a post request with authentication token in header i got a 401 - Unauthorized server error.

My production environment is Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 server with proxy set to redirect from port 80 to port 5000 (this is the place where API is).

On development environment everything worked perfectly without any error so I guess that there is something with transferring request header from apache to kestrel.

I tried to google this problem and on Microsoft's website I found that I need to use forwarded headers method in my startup.cs file like this:

`app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseAuthentication();`

I configured my startup class like that but without any success.
Any help or direction where to try to find the solution would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a custome header throgh middleware.

```
namespace Middleware
{
public class CustomHeader
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomHeader(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context,
    {

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",new string[]{ "authorization" }
            }
        };

        //To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
        context.Response.OnStarting(state => {
            var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
            foreach (var item in dictionary)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }, context);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the location of this namespace? Seems that I don't have it in my project.

Comment: It's a custom namespace. It's the custom code if you want to create a middle ware to inject anything in the response. You can read more about it in microsoft docs.